# Magento as low as price displays on some pages but not all?

Tags: magento

price has disappeared from some pages - http://www.internetvoipphone.co.uk/yealink.html

but still shows on cisco page, cant figure out why, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxes.css line 642 is this:

.grid-row .item .price-box .regular-price .price { display: none; }

Which is hiding the prices.

Comment: Hi Thanks Joseph, but that hides the regular price, not the minimal price as far as i'm aware?

Comment: The HTML and CSS appear to have changed since I looked last. I see a "full" price (say 40 quid) and then the now-displayed price (37 quid). What are you expecting to see?